# any and not any function

Tags: python, new-operator, any

i'm currently trying to learn python. I had some queries while i was attempting this question.

Write a program that asks the user to enter a password, and then checks if the password meets certain criteria (e.g. at least 8 characters, contains both uppercase and lowercase letters, etc.). If the password does not meet the criteria, the program should ask the user to enter a new password until they enter a valid one using a while loop and if statements.

This is my code, i am trying to use the any operator to check for at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter when i enter my password. My password was MinkMink123, the any operator return true for my password however it deemed my password as invalid. May i know why is this so?

```
while True:
    password = input("Enter a password: ")
    print(f"len(password) = {len(password)}")
    print(f"any(c.isupper() for c in password) = {any(c.isupper() for c in password)}")
    print(f"any(c.islower() for c in password) = {any(c.islower() for c in password)}")
    if len(password) < 8:
        print("Password must be at least 8 characters long.")
        continue
    elif any(c.isupper() for c in password):
        print("Password must contain at least one uppercase letter.")
        continue
    elif any(c.islower() for c in password):
        print("Password must contain at least one lowercase letter.")
        continue
    else:
        print("Password is valid.")
        break
```

i tried chatgpt and the result was changing the any function to not any function but i dont understand why. Please kindly educate me

Comment: Shouldn't it be `elif not any(c.isupper() for c in password):`? (note the `not`). And the same for `islower`

Comment: Think about it. If any letter is uppercase, the first `elif` is valid. So you enter its block, which says the password must contain one uppercase letter. You obviously want the opposite, you want to enter this block only if **none** of the letters were uppercase. Hence the `not`. `not any` is just the negation of `any`, returning True if any was False.

Comment: Also, to avoid going through the string multiple times, I'd suggest storing the results of `any(...)`s in the variables. Your mistake will be more apparent as well.

Comment: Terminology note: `any` is not an operator; it's an ordinary function. Operators are tokens like `+`, `-`, etc that are implemented using methods defined on the type(s) involved.

Answer (score 0):

`any(mask)` returns `True` as long as `mask` has at least one entry that is `True`, i.e. **any** value.

What you want to check is if **none** of the entries of `mask` is `True`, in which case the password is invalid. Therefore, you should indeed change your `any` to `not any`.

Comment: `not any(...)`, a.k.a. `all(not ...)`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych that's incorrect. `not mask` will not return the flipped mask, but instead will try to convert the list object to a boolean, and negate that, so it will return `False`, AFAIK unless `mask` is `None`.


With numpy boolean arrays, you could use `all(~mask)`, however that is less efficient, since it first negates the whole array, and then performs the horizontal reduction, while `not any(mask)` only negates a single boolean after the horizontal reduction.

Comment: @bathal I guess he meant `not any(el for el in l)` == `all(not el for el in l)` also known as De Morgan's law.

Answer (score 0):

You want to enter in the blocks if the password has no uppercase (then lowercase). Currently you write "if any uppercase in my password : enter in the block".

As it has been said in comments, you need to use `not any` instead of `any`.